# Access table field inside CREATE TRIGGER statement

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, trigger, plpgsql

How can I access table field on creating a trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc(foo.field);  -- here goes the parameter
```

Answer (score 4):

[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) on how to create a trigger function:

> The trigger function must be defined before the trigger itself can be
> created. The trigger function must be declared as a function **taking no
> arguments** and returning type trigger. (The `trigger` function receives
> its input through a specially-passed `TriggerData` structure, not in the
> form of ordinary function arguments.)

Bold emphasis mine.

[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) on how to pass parameters:

> ```
> arguments
> ```
>
> An optional comma-separated list of arguments to be provided to the
> function when the trigger is executed. The arguments are literal
> string constants. Simple names and numeric constants can be written
> here, too, but they will all be converted to strings. Please check the
> description of the implementation language of the trigger function to
> find out how these arguments can be accessed within the function; it
> might be different from normal function arguments.

And finally, in the chapter ["Trigger Procedures"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> Note that the function must be declared with no arguments even if it
> expects to receive arguments specified in `CREATE TRIGGER` — trigger
> arguments are passed via `TG_ARGV`, as described below.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> TG_ARGV[]
> ```
>
> Data type array of `text`; the arguments from the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement. The index counts from 0. Invalid indexes (less than 0 or greater than or equal to `tg_nargs`) result in a null value.

The final difficulty is that SQL only works with static identifiers. If you want to parametrize a column name, you need **dynamic SQL**. Use [**`EXECUTE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in a PL/pgSQL function.

#### Example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_foo()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _result text;
BEGIN
   CASE TG_OP
   WHEN 'INSERT', 'UPDATE' THEN
      EXECUTE format('SELECT %I FROM %s WHERE tbl_id = $1', TG_ARGV[1]
                                                          , TG_ARGV[0]::regclass)
      INTO  _result
      USING NEW.sometbl_id;
   WHEN ...

   END CASE;

   -- do something with _result ...

   RETURN NULL;   -- since it's an AFTER trigger
END
$func$;


CREATE TRIGGER foo_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_foo('foo', 'field'); -- two params: table, field
```

Outdated versions of Postgres still require the keyword `PROCEDURE` instead of `FUNCTION`. See:

- [Trigger uses a procedure or a function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307492/trigger-uses-a-procedure-or-a-function/307500#307500)

Schema-qualify the table name to avoid ambiguity. Like `'public.foo'`.
Details for the cast to `regclass`:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)