# Use default value instead of inserted null

Tags: postgresql, trigger, default-value

I have a table definition in Postgres that use `now()` for timestamp and `current_user()` for auditing.

```
date_created date NULL DEFAULT now(),
edited_by varchar NULL DEFAULT "current_user"(),
```

The problem is that the server produces queries with explicit null values if not given other instructions. I have no way of changing the query being sent from the server to pg.

```
INSERT INTO test_table
    (notes, date, edited_by)
    VALUES('test', null, null);
```

Is there a way to still use these default values somehow? Or is the solution to write a trigger function to solve it?

Comment: I can't think of a different solution other than a trigger

Comment: Looks like you are right. Solved it with trigger

Answer (score 2):

A trigger is the right **workaround** if your problem can't be fixed.

You stated:

> The problem is that the server produces queries with explicit null
> values if not given other instructions. I have no way of changing the
> query being sent from the server to pg.

The right **solution** would be to "give other instructions". Or replace that "server" of yours with decent software if it's incapable (which I doubt).

Additionally, define both columns `NOT NULL` to raise an exception if the error should still happen (unless you need to allow `NULL` values).

If you have to add that trigger after all, make it efficient:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION force_user_defaults()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.date_created := now();
   NEW.edited_by    := current_user();
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER test_table_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON test_table
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.date_created IS NULL OR NEW.edited_by IS NULL)  -- !
EXECUTE FUNCTION force_user_defaults();
```

The point being to only even call the trigger function if violating `NULL` values are passed. Note then `WHEN` clause in [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) - which only makes sense if those `NULL` values are the exception rather than the rule.

About `EXECUTE FUNCTION`:

- [Trigger uses a procedure or a function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307492/trigger-uses-a-procedure-or-a-function/307500#307500)

Answer (score -2):

```
create table test_table (
notes varchar,
date_created date NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
edited_by varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT "current_user"()
);

INSERT INTO test_table
    (notes)
    VALUES('test');
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation to go with your answer? Otherwise it's just a piece of code that might (or might not) solve the question.